# org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration does not exist in hadoop-core.jar

Tags: maven, hadoop, hbase, cloudera

I am writing an HBase client in Java. The first line, of coz, looks like this:

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;

I am using Cloudera CDH4.3.1, so the package versions should be:

```
hadoop-2.0.0+1367
hbase-0.94.6+106
```

==**Updated**==

my pom.xml looks like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
  <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.3.1</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
  <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
  <version>0.94.6-cdh4.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

But somehow, in hadoop-core.jar, I am not seeing any existence of  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration. As the result of it, the import is not resolved by Java obviously.

Comment: Why does your hbase not use a CDH version? Such as 0.94.6-cdh4.3.1

Comment: good point, I was using local hbase jar at 1st. I just updated it to cdh version as well. But as expected, that would make any difference in this case.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add hadoop-common to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>                                                                                                                                       
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>                                                                                                           
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>                                                                                                         
    <version>2.0.0-cdh4.3.1</version>                                                                                            
</dependency>
```