# error in resolving org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration

Tags: java, apache, maven, hadoop, hdfs

I want to write files to hdfs present on a remote server and came across few examples like [this](http://paulscott.co.za/blog/uploading-files-through-java-api-to-hdfs-the-easy-way/) and [this](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!topic/cdh-user/oYTv5YCjSwI). I have *Cdh4.2.1* on my remote server and when from my code I try to do `import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;`, I get the following error:

`Cannot resolve Configuration`

My pom.xml looks like:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414151/org-apache-hadoop-conf-configuration-does-not-exist-in-hadoop-core-jar) SO post, the pom.xml looks different and when I try to put those `versions` in my pom, the maven does not recognize it.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try using just the `hadoop-client` dependency and use cloudera specific version as you are using CDH like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
  <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-cdh4.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Also make sure you have the following repositories to resolve the jar dependencies:

```
<repository>
  <id>maven-hadoop</id>
  <name>Hadoop Releases</name>
  <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/</url>
</repository>
<repository>
  <id>cloudera-repos</id>
  <name>Cloudera Repos</name>
  <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
</repository>
```