# not able to execute jar file with maven dependancy

Tags: java, hadoop, jar, pom.xml

I am trying to execute jar file but it shows below error:

`java -jar HDFSTest1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration
at hdfstest1.HDFSTestGUI1.<init>(HDFSTestGUI1.java:48)
at hdfstest1.HDFSTestGUI1$17.run(HDFSTestGUI1.java:561)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 16 more
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>HDFSTest1</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jdesktop</groupId>
        <artifactId>beansbinding</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <mainClass>hdfstest1.HDFSTestGUI1</mainClass>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>hdfstest1.HDFSTestGUI1</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>hdfstest1.HDFSTestGUI1</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Manifest.mf:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: dipsi
Class-Path: hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar commons-cli-1.2.jar xmlenc-0.52.jar 
jersey-core-1.8.jar jersey-json-1.8.jar jettison-1.1.jar stax-api-1.0
.1.jar jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar stax-api-1.0-2.jar ac
tivation-1.1.jar jackson-core-asl-1.7.1.jar jackson-jaxrs-1.7.1.jar j
ackson-xc-1.7.1.jar jersey-server-1.8.jar asm-3.1.jar commons-io-2.1.
jar commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar junit-3.8.1.jar commons-logging-1.0.
3.jar commons-codec-1.4.jar commons-math-2.1.jar commons-configuratio
n-1.6.jar commons-collections-3.2.1.jar commons-lang-2.4.jar commons-
digester-1.8.jar commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar commons-beanutils-core-1
.8.0.jar commons-net-1.4.1.jar jetty-6.1.26.jar servlet-api-2.5-20081
 211.jar jetty-util-6.1.26.jar jasper-runtime-5.5.12.jar jasper-compil
 er-5.5.12.jar jsp-api-2.1-6.1.14.jar servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar jsp-2
 .1-6.1.14.jar ant-1.6.5.jar commons-el-1.0.jar jets3t-0.6.1.jar hsqld
 b-1.8.0.10.jar oro-2.0.8.jar core-3.1.1.jar jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.  

 jar beansbinding-1.2.1.jar
 Created-By: Apache Maven 3.0.5
 Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_121
 Main-Class: hdfstest1.HDFSTestGUI1
```

I have tried almost all the solutions available in the internet but I think I am missing something which I am not be able to understand here. can someone help to to understand this?
Thanks in advance!!

I have used hadoop-core.jar (1.2.1) which includes all modules such as mapreduce,hadoop-common etc. Do I need to add it explicitly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration does not exist in hadoop-core.jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414151/org-apache-hadoop-conf-configuration-does-not-exist-in-hadoop-core-jar)

Comment: @sinclair I have used hadoop-core.jar 1.2.1 which already includes hadoop-common package

Comment: Is it an uber-jar with all dependencies included?

Comment: @DaveNewton nop. I have not used uber-jar. Do I need to use it?

Comment: If you run Java with `java -jar` you either have to have everything in that jar, or set up the classpass in the jar manifest.  There's also the `mvn exec` plugin which will run your code in the Maven classpath context (or something like that; I barely remember any Java).

Comment: @DaveNewton I have everything in classpath when I check my manifest file except this conf. class all jars are available. would you please suggest me which needs to be updated in my pom.xml file?

Comment: You should show your manifest then. Diagnosing issues is difficult without information.

Comment: @DaveNewton Added manifest file

Comment: Are those libraries in the current directory from where you're running the jar? I'm guessing no.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't `$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar HDFSTest1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` command be used for running hadoop jobs?

If all the jars are fine in the classpath then I do not see any other faults other than this.